# What are the possible causes of a vector subscript out of range error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm learning to use Visual Studio after spending the last semester coding in Xcode.  I wrote a simple function to shuffle a vector that holds different names of restaurants in strings as follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

//shuffles all the restaurants
void shuffler(vector<string>& restaurvector)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    vector<string> shuffled;
    long initialSize = restaurvector.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < initialSize; i++)
    {
        // get a random number between 0 and the current vector size
        int randomOfRest = rand() % restaurvector.size();
        // locate a random element in the original vector and set it as
        // the next element in the shuffled vector
        shuffled.push_back(restaurvector[randomOfRest]);
        // delete the element that was copied and shift remaining elements
        for (int j = randomOfRest; j < restaurvector.size(); j++)
        {
            restaurvector[j] = restaurvector[j + 1];
        }
        restaurvector.pop_back();
    }
    restaurvector = shuffled;
    cout << "\nThe restaurant vector has been shuffled.\n";
}
```

When I run this same program in Xcode, it compiles and runs perfectly.  When I run this program from Visual Studio, I get a runtime error that looks like this:

[image]

I checked my code to make sure I wasn't referencing elements that don't exist but no matter what I do, it doesn't run properly.  What happened?  Why doesn't it run in Visual Studio like it does in Xcode?

Comment: `restaurvector[j + 1]` when `j=restaurvector.size()-1` is out of range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for (int j = randomOfRest; j < restaurvector.size(); j++)

    {
        restaurvector[j] = restaurvector[j + 1];
    }
```

that does a j+1, meaning it will go over the end.

this will fix the problem

```
for (int j = randomOfRest; j < restaurvector.size()-1; j++)
```

Comment: So if I change it to `restaurvector[j - 1] = restaurvector[j]` will that fix it?

Comment: if you did that, if randomOfRest was 0, it would cause an issue

Comment: Ok got it.  I'll accept your answer in six minutes.  Any idea why Xcode allowed this error and worked fine but Visual Studio didn't?  That's the real question.

Comment: notice it says "Debug Assertion", Its trying to help you write code that does what you expect.  In Release this would likely just work because in your case you never try to use the last item.  But technically its wrong, and could go nuts.   I'm sure Xcode is allowing it, but you are going outside your bounds and because you discard that last item without trying to use it ( which was copied from outside the bounds) then it also is ok.

Comment: Okay that makes sense.  I guess I just have to be more careful...I feel like Xcode lets lots of things go that maybe it shouldn't.

Comment: Lots of C and C++ compilers do the same thing, just the better ones try to help you, if you are lucky!  Having to deal with lots of embedded compilers, I mostly get screwed in these cases. heck I often have to deal with the fact the compilers can sometimes generate the wrong code!

Answer (score 1):

The code fails on the line `restaurvector[j] = restaurvector[j + 1];` because `restaurvector[j + 1]` at `j = restaurvector.size()-1` is out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the last iteration of this loop:

```
for (int j = randomOfRest; j < restaurvector.size(); j++)
{
    restaurvector[j] = restaurvector[j + 1];
}
```

accesses an item out of bounds (`restaurvector[j + 1]`).

But instead of this, why not just erase the item `randomOfRest`?

```
   restaurvector.erase(restaurvector.begin() + randomOfRest);
```

The erasure will move the items up in the vector, so you don't need a loop to do this.

Comment: I'd prefer just to erase items like that but for our beginner C++ class we're required to use loops to erase items in a vector.  I'll keep that in mind for the future though.

Comment: @Brandon Why not just say "I looked up what vector has, and I saw that the erase function did the job"?  Why would you get penalized for doing research?  That should be commended.

Comment: They want us to practice using loops.  It's a very basic beginner class.  Most of the students probably won't take any other programming classes afterward.  I agree though - if it's easier and functional, we should be allowed to use it.  Just like I'd like to do our final project in Xcode rather than Visual Studio.

Comment: @Brandon Loops are simple, so there really is no real *practice* you can get out of them.   Reading the documentation of the container you're using and then using the functions provided to you *is* the real skill.  Also, you become disciplined in that you look for documented solutions first, rather than falling back and attempting to roll your own code.